# Does a Mining World designation improve strategic resource synthesis?

Tags: stellaris

The Mining World designation improves mining and "Strategic Resource Gatherers".  I assume this means that the miners of a strategic resource get a bonus amount of that resource.  What I'm not clear on is: **Does a mining world designation improve artificial conversion of minerals into strategic resources as well?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the mining world designation increased the output of miners and strategic resource **gatherers** (that is, mote harvesters, crystal miners and gas extractors).

If you want to increase the output of the jobs that transform minerals in strategic resources (chemists, translucers and gas refiners) you need to select **refinery world** as designation for that planet.

https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Designation